# Sort a list of Integers using a Collator

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator, collator

We're using the following simplified code snipped for sorting.

```
    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    collator.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);
    return Comparator.comparing(entity -> {
        try {
            // Custom stuff here...
            // Values processed here cn be either String, Integer, Boolean or Date
            return (Comparable)sortFieldValue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }, collator);
```

This is working fine for `String` values. However we'd like to reuse this to also compare `Boolean`, `Integer`, etc. With the given collator this results in:

`java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

When removing the collator sorting also works for ther data types than `String` but then e.g. German umlauts are not sorted as desired.

What could be an adequate way to "combine" using the collator for string-based values and ignoring it for other data types?

Comment: Unrelated: `throw new RuntimeException();`... you better do: `throw new RuntimeException(e);` ... your current code throws away all the details of the initial exception. I am also wondering why exactly you are doing that in the first place.

Comment: `Collator`s can only be used to compare `String`s, maybe call `entity.toString()` to convert it to `String`?

Comment: @GhostCat You're right. I pretty much stripped down the code. The actual code does include the `(e)`. The reason why we are doing it this way is that we'd like to have one place which can sort different data types coming in from a JSON via a REST API. This JSON can include strings, numbers, etc.

Comment: @Lino Thanks for the hint. This seems to do the trick, at least for most of the cases. I'll stick to that variant until we maybe find another way.

Comment: @RobertStrauch Maybe use `String.valueOf(entity)`, which handles also `null` values

Comment: A `Collator` affects the order of *letters*. An `Integer` doesn’t contains letters, even if you convert it to a `String` before comparing. Further, a `Collector` is normally used to get some natural ordering form a human’s perspective. Sorting numbers by their string representation leads to an unnatural result.

Comment: What challenges you find for - **What could be an adequate way to "combine" using the collator for string-based values and ignoring it for other data types?** ? Looks like a simple decision problem based on input types as `Collator` is a `Comparator` too.

Comment: You should be more specific about the “Custom stuff here”. The comment says that the resulting value can be “either String, Integer, Boolean or Date”, but comparing a mixture of these types would not work even when not using a `Collator`. Perhaps, the type is always the same, depending on a condition that doesn’t change during a particular sort operation. Then, it would be better to identify that condition and pre-check it, to use a dedicated comparator for the current type of a sort operation, instead of trying to handle all of them in a single comparator.

Answer (score 0):

What we do is check the type of the entity being compared and only use the collator (via collator.compare(..)) if both values are actually strings.